# Create array of strings using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to create an array of strings in C. I want the computer to accept value from the user and store it in string `name[31]`. This should happen till the user enters <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. When the user types in a name,  store it in another array called `storage`.

My code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char name[31];
    char *storage[31];
    int i = 0;
    //Reading the name
    while( (int) name != EOF )
    {
        sscanf("%s", name);
        *storage[i] = &name;
        i++;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 31 ; i ++)
    {

        printf("%s", *storage[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'When the user types in a name, store it in another array called storage'?

Comment: I think he wants to read lines of up to 30 characters, storing each line in an entry of `storage[31][N]`, stopping when the user enters the `end-of-transmission` character (often entered via Ctrl+D, often shown as `^D`).

Comment: Yess. Mooing Duck is right.

Comment: But what is your *question*? What is preventing you from writing this program? If you don't know where to start, you really need to pick up a book and start to learn the fundamentals of C programming. If there's something specific that you're stuck on, show us the code and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: If You dont have any restriction about the Maximus number of lines that You recive as input You may consider to use a list.

Comment: If you dont want to use a list, you can use the function realloc

Comment: Could you show how? I am not good with pointers :/ and we have to use malloc and realloc

Comment: First you allocate your array char** storage=(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAX))

Comment: Now for each storage[i] with i from 0 to MAX - 1 you allocate it with malloc(sizeof(char)*31)

Comment: Now, each time you want to grow your array, storage, this is, when you read more than MAX lines, you just use realloc over it and then initialize the new storage [i] with i from MAX to NEWMAX

Comment: NEWMAX is the size gou want to realloc which needs to be higher than MAX

Comment: NEWMAX is the size gou want to realloc which needs to be higher than MAX

Comment: Also dont forget to update the values in the end MAX = NEWMAX.

Comment: If you implement this using a list, it will be mutch more faster and pretty

Comment: I dont quite get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help. It is limited to 31 names, you will still need to figure out realloc. It will stop if Ctrl+D is typed or you enter 31 names.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char name[31];
    char *storage[31]; // declares 31 pointers to char
    int i = 0;
    int iEach;
    //Reading the name
    while( fgets ( name, 31, stdin) > 0 )  // names may contain spaces so use fgets
    {

        storage[i] = malloc ( strlen(name) + 1); // allocate storage for each name
        strcpy ( storage[i], name); // copy the name to the array
        i++;
        if ( i == 31) { // out of pointers so exit the while loop
            break;
        }
    }
    for ( iEach = 0; iEach < i ; iEach ++)
    {

        printf("%s", storage[iEach]);
    }
    for ( iEach = 0; iEach < i ; iEach ++)
    {

        free ( storage[iEach]); // free allocated memory
    }
    return 0;
}
```